# Create stack space within a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, stack

I have:

```
  typedef struct{
   int *stack;
   int *stack_ptr;
  }MyStruct;
```

then somewhere else I do:

```
MyStruct *temp = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
temp->stack = malloc(1024) //allocate 1024 bytes
temp->stack_ptr = temp->stack;  //stack_ptr points to beginning of stack
temp->stack_ptr += 800;  //move stack_ptr down towards bottom of stack
```

I'm trying to make sense of the debugger output and I don't think this is right, but I can't tell for sure.  I just want to have a stack within my struct and then a stack pointer within this stack that I can manipulate.

EDIT:  Okay, the part about adding 800 makes sense.  I guess what I'm having trouble understanding is after I allocate 1024 bytes for temp->stack, how do I go about inserting something down towards the bottom of that stack?  Do I even need to have the stack_ptr or is there a way to offset stack variable.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is here.

Comment: Note that since you built your stack using an `int`, when you do `+= 800`, you're not shifting 800 bytes, your shifting `800*sizeof(int)` bytes

Comment: no matter what your real question is, leaving any variable uninitialized is a really bad idea, especially for pointers .

Comment: What is `temp_stack`? Should that be `temp->stack`?

Comment: If it's output you don't understand, perhaps you should post that too (and say what is unclear about it).

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, really, but maybe you're looking for the `alloca` syscall? (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html)

Comment: " inserting something down towards the bottom of that stack" - eh?  A stack is a LIFO structure ; you can only push onto it.   You can write `*temp->stack_ptr = 123;`. Yes, you could use an offset instead of a poitner, those are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is likely that you think

```
temp->stack_ptr += 800;  //move stack_ptr down towards bottom of stack
```

would advance your stack pointer to the 800th stack entry. It doesn't, it moves the stack pointer to 800 * sizeof(int) bytes (likely 3200), while you allocated only 1024 bytes.
If you need to dynamically allocate `n` items of something, the idiomatic C code is

```
sometype *foo;
/* ... */
foo = malloc (n * sizeof (*foo));
```

The `sizeof` multiplication is usually omitted for pointers-to-char since `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition of the C Language Standard.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I updated my question with more information as to the other part that is confusing me.

Answer (score -1):

```
temp->stack = malloc(1024) //allocate 1024 bytes
```

Should be:

```
temp->stack = malloc(1024 * sizeof(int)); //allocate 1024 bytes
```

What exactly is your problem ??

**Edit**

Let me explain what i meant by that:

Your are trying to move your pointer of 800 blocks (800 * sizeof(int)) but you only allocate 1024 = 1024 / sizeof(int) blocks

Comment: This should be a comment, considering it is not clear what exactly the question is

Comment: I'nm guessing he has some kind of seg fault